# Column created using alter and NOT NULL constraint

Tags: sql, database, oracle

There is a scenario where we have created a table. After populating data into it, we altered the table and created a new column say, 'CITY'. After creating this column making it as NOT NULL, we did not populated any data in it. So what will be the values of row in this case in CITY column?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? What happened when you tried?

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? You shouldn't be allowed to set column to NOT NULL if it has NULLs in it. (Or specify a default value at the same time.)

Comment: Or MSSQL? if MSSQL - You can't add NOT NULL column on existing tables without definition of DEFAULT() value. If DEFAULT is defined, then for all old rows it will have default value.

Comment: Try this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a scenario where we have created a table. After populating data into it, we altered the table and created a new column say, 'CITY'. After creating this column making it as NOT NULL, we did not populated any data in it. So what will be the values of row in this case in CITY column?

No you cannot.

If you directly try to add a new column with **NOT NULL** constraint to **existing table having rows**, you would simply get following error:

```
ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
```

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT LEVEL a FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (b NUMBER NOT NULL);
ALTER TABLE t ADD (b NUMBER NOT NULL)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column


SQL>
```

If you try to **ALTER** the table and MODIFY to add the NOT NULL constraint, then you would receive following error:

```
ORA-02296: cannot enable (LALIT.B_C) - null values found
```

For example,

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT LEVEL a FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD (b NUMBER);

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> ALTER TABLE t
  2  MODIFY (b NUMBER CONSTRAINT b_c NOT NULL);
MODIFY (b NUMBER CONSTRAINT b_c NOT NULL)
                            *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (LALIT.B_C) - null values found
```

So, there is no way possible that you could create a new column with NOT NULL constraint on an existing table having rows. The table must be empty.

Comment: Great answer! (Just too bad if MySQL and not Oracle is used...)

Comment: @jarlh I didn't see OP tagged mysql too. Let's wait for OP to confirm.

Comment: @NeeteshRajoriya Please mark it as answered. And edit your question to remove the mysql tag.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: mysql tag is removed. how can I mark it as answered?

Comment: @NeeteshRajoriya In my answer on top left side, were you see an upvote button, there is a tick mark, click on it, it would turn green which means you accept this as an answer. You will get some reputation for accepting. Please go through the `Stack Overflow tour` to know more about this beautiful site.